# Populating a list view with from a Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

So my question is I created a listview and populated it using a simple cursor adapter. So now when I click an item on my listview it takes me to another activity which suppose to show me the details of the item I clicked. What is the best approach on going about this? Here is my function of populating the list view. What exactly should I be sending to the next activity? I was thinking about sending the position but then that wouldnt work because in the next activity I would have to access the database using the position but that wouldnt be accurate because the database could have rows deleted which can return me a different row of data. Any ideas would be truly appreciated.

```
private void populateListView(){

    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getAllData();
    String[] fromfieldNames = new String[]{StudentDBOpenHelper.ITEM_NAME_COLUMN};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.textView_itemName};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.indvidualview_layout,cursor,fromfieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.courseListXML);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), CourseWorkItemActivity.class);

            nextActivity.putExtra("Item", position);

            startActivity(nextActivity);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest sending the data, extracted from the cursor as intent extras. Here's an example (a little more complicated that what you want, as on `Itemclick` I display an intermediate dialog to select Edit or Stock (place products into a aisle in a shop) options. :-

```
productlist_csr = shopperdb.getProductsAsCursor();
        currentpca = new ProductsCursorAdapter(this, productlist_csr, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        productlistview.setAdapter(currentpca);

        productlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder okdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(productlistview_context);
                okdialog.setTitle(R.string.productlistentryclicktitle);
                okdialog.setMessage(R.string.productlistentryclickmessage001);
                okdialog.setCancelable(true);
                final int pos = position;
                okdialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.standardstockproductlist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(productlistview_context, AddProductToShopActivity.class);
                        productlist_csr.moveToPosition(pos);
                        intent.putExtra("Caller", THIS_ACTIVITY);
                        intent.putExtra("PRODUCTID", productlist_csr.getLong(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("ProductName", productlist_csr.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("ProductNotes", productlist_csr.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NOTES_INDEX));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.standardedittext, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(productlistview_context, ProductAddActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Caller", THIS_ACTIVITY + "Update");
                        productlist_csr.moveToPosition(pos);
                        intent.putExtra("ProductName", productlist_csr.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("ProductNotes", productlist_csr.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NOTES_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("PRODUCTID", productlist_csr.getLong(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.standardbacktext, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Note! `ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_?????_INDEX` equates to the respective column's offset into the cursor. I use the intent Extra **Caller** to notify the started activity of the calling activity (eg Stock can be called from a product, a shop or an aisle) so that it can act accordingly.

In the above `position` is used to to move to the respective cursor row (*However, I believe that this isn't actually needed as the cursor will already be positioned, but do this just in case*).

I also use a custom cursor but that shouldn't, I believe, be an issue (I've never used simpleCursor).

Comment: I will try this! Thank you.

Comment: One thing to note, is that on return from the started activity, if that activity changes the database, you should redo the query and reset the adapter to use the new/modified cursor via `changeCursor`, `swapCursor` or `notifyDataSetCahnged` (I've used swapCursor and do this in the onresume method).  eg `currentproductsperaisleecursor = shopperdb.getProductsperAisle(currentaisleid);
                // Swap to this cursor
                current_productsperaislecursoradapter.swapCursor(currentproductsperaisleecursor);`